# I'm building a create-next-app and i have to call data from a web api, but i don't know where to store the API key

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, api, next.js

I'm trying to create a create-next-app which fetch data from https://newscatcherapi.com/free-news-api and displaying it on my app.

I got API key to access the API. But i don't where to save the API key and make call to fetch the API with API key.

Expecting any links to resources or any other answers to learn API call with api key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

API keys are something you don't want to share, so what you want to do is to keep them on your server so no one will be able to see them this also means that you need to fetch the data using your api key on the server and then send the final data, you can do it by using api route in app dir or now by using server action which I would personally not recommend due to this feature being currently in alpha so here is a way to implement an api.
https://youtu.be/vrR4MlB7nBI

Back to where to store your api keys we prefer to store them using something called Environment Variables which you can read more about here they will not be exposed to the browser if not specified.

https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/environment-variables

Comment: Worked on it. Now i got the idea of fetching API. I just stored the API key in a environment variable and accessed it to the headers while fetching the API.